# PHP- Print a String letter by letter in HTML-form Vertically

Tags: php, html, string, printing, letter

I want to print these letters in a HTML-form vertically, now it's in horizontal form.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title></title>     
</head>
<body>
<?php
     $sentence = "What is your first name";
     $letters = str_replace(" ", "", $sentence);
     $letters_array = str_split($letters);

?>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">

<?php
    for($n = 0; $n < strlen($letters); $n++){
        print "<td> " . $letters_array[$n] . " </td>";
        if(($n+1) % 5 == 0){
            print "<tr> ";
        }
    }

?>

</table>
```

Comment: simply use css.... :)

Comment: The question does not show research or attempt at solving from the author's side.

Comment: Use foreach as well, it'll will make your life easier in this case. It is very lazy question though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open and close`<tr></tr>`

Expand 
`print "<td> " . $letters_array[$n] . " </td>";`

to

```
print "<tr><td> " . $letters_array[$n] . " </td></tr>";
```

And

```
<td></td>
```

means table datacell, cells are placed horizontally, until a new row begins.

Answer (score 0):

The output is something like this now:

---

|W |h |a |t |i|

---

|s |y |o |u |r|

I want it like this:

---

|W |s |f |n |

---

|h |y |i |a |

---

|a |o |r |m |

---

|t |u |s |e |

---

|i |r |t |

I can't upload pics, that's why I wrote this like a table.

Comment: ´if(($n+1) % 5 == 0){
            print "<tr> ";
        }´ needs to be removed, and you need much more logic if you want it like that. HTML is written left to right, but you need to know what character $n+$number_of_rows is by the time you write second column.

Comment: You need: `print "<tr>";` before loop starts, and you need `print "<td>".$letters_array[$n]."</td><td>".$letters_array[$n+$number_of_rows]."</td>";` inside of the for-loop. Then `if ($n=$number_of_rows) {echo "</tr><tr>";}';` inside of loop as well. etcetc.